# How to insert data into multiple tables using codeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I am working on MVC Framework (codeIgniter)

```
tbl_emp, tbl_address, tbl_salary
```

I created 3 tables in one database, and now i want to pass the data into 3 tables by using single query using INSERT . Please help me out with this query...

Comment: you want to ass data into 3 tables using a single SQL (tag for the question?) statement?
did you read some SQL toturials/learning material already?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in one statement but you can do it in transaction :

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query('INSERT QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER INSERT QUERY...');
$this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER INSERT QUERY...');
$this->db->trans_complete();
```